# Drill through in Power Bi Heatmap visual is not working

Tags: powerbi, heatmap, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to visualize some data on a heatmap. I can do it with the heatmap visual, but it does not have the drill-through functionality. Can someone confirm if I am making a mistake or not?

Also, I tried to use Filled Map visual, it works perfectly except I cannot have it as a heatmap. So can someone direct me in the right direction on how I can create my heatmap and have a drill-through functionality?

This is the heatmap app I used:

[image]

Drill through works with a filled map:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the heat map feature on the Microsoft-provided Azure Maps visual:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/power-bi-visual-add-heat-map-layer

Comment: I liked the visual but it does not have a drill through option